# Appropriate algorithms for interpolating 2D plane

Tags: algorithms, interpolation

I have a dataset describing a signal on a 2D plane.

The data can be spaced at arbitrary increments.  If it was an ordered grid, I understand bicubic interpolation would be a good choice. In the absence of an ordered grid what kind of algorithms are best at handling that kind of dataset?

I do have control over where I sample the data, and eventually I will likely be interpolating to an evenly spaced grid, but preferably that wouldn't be a constraint. The data in the signal is 3 parts, one part of the signal increases on the x axis, the other part of the signal increases in the y axis and the third piece of data stays relatively constant. Although the rate of change varies for the increasing signals and varies relative to the opposing axis.  The constant data also fluctuates typically getting smaller as it approaches the origin.

As far as the sample spacing goes, I have control over that, the output size isn't huge typically I'll be interpolating to a maximum of 65x65 evenly spaced points with the same spacing for both x and y axis.   Due to time limitations, I can only collect about 100 samples to seed the interpolation algorithm.

I'm a .net programmer at the edge math knowledge, so if there is a math library that contains the algorithm it would be even better.

Comment: Interpolation is a vast subject. The choice of a good method depends on many things, including the statistical and physical nature of the data, expectations about the mathematical and statistical properties of the interpolated function, the geometry of the data locations, how those locations were selected, and the purpose of the interpolation. To make this question sufficiently narrow to be answerable here, please edit it to supply this information.

Comment: updated the question with more details about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: See this answer - everything stated here is relevant for 2D spatial interpolation as well.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242119/how-can-i-interpolate-a-time-series-subject-to-stochastic-perturbation/242120#242120